# Partials outside of parent controller rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am truly at a dead on how to solve rending a partial for a user. I have an app where a users has book and each book has many chapters. So user A would create a book and chapter and the url looks like so site.com/book/1/chapter/1. What I am trying to do is when a user is logged in I would like to show the users recent chapters, or recent credits

**content/home.html.erb**

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <%= render 'dashboard/home'%>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'homepage'%>
<% end %>
```

**blocks/_user_chapters.html.erb**

```
<% @user.chapters.each do |chapter| %>
  <%= div_for chapter do  %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= chapter.title %></td>
      <td><%= chapter.body %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'View Chapter', book_chapter_path %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**dashboard/_home.html.erb**

```
<%= content_tag :h1, "Recent Chapters" %>
<%= render 'blocks/user_chapters', :locals => {:book => @book} %>
```

When I reload the page from above I get the ***undefined method `chapter' for book:0x007fd996697630*** .Even if I go into book/1/ I still cannot see the user recent chapters.

How can I access a logged in users recent chapters, or books anywhere in my rails app?

Comment: Is 'shared/user_chapters' the same as 'block/user_chapters'?

Comment: Are model's relations correct?

Comment: Model relations are correct and it was a typo I meant blocks not shared

Comment: Shouldn't that be `book.chapters.each` in the first line of your partial?

Comment: when I add book.chapter.each I get undefined method chapters and I am sure my associations are setup correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it appears that you have a partial in `blocks/_user_chapters.html.erb` but you are trying to access it via `render 'shared/user_chapters'`. You need to move '_user_chapters.html.erb' into `app/views/shared` in order to use it.

Comment: I think I mistyped name its not shared its blocks It was a typo

Comment: @coletrain What line of your code causes `undefined method 'chapter' for book:0x007fd996697630` error? That seems like `.chaper` is being called on a book object. This may be a totally unrelated error.

Comment: this seems to be the line that is causing errors `<% @user.chapters.each do |chapter| %>`

Comment: I think I may have answered my question. I dont think I can access a chapter outside of books because rails cannot find a id. I was able to get it to work by calling books.chapters.each and accessing it through the book_id such as book/2 or book/3